# SQL query to get recently created users in OIM

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

Is there a SQL query for users created in OIM. There are no dates provided while creating users in OIM, But we need to find the users on the basis of their creation date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from usr where to_date(usr_create)>to_date('01-Jun-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```